# How to Transform in to one function using generics or dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two methods which are very similar. How would I extract the common functionality into one function using generics (or dynamic .NET features)?

```
private IEnumerable<BlogPost> GetBlogPostToday(IBlogPostRepository repo)
{
    return repo
        .GetAllQueryAble()
        .Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DateAdded) == DateTime.Today)
        .Select(p => p).AsEnumerable();
}

private IEnumerable<BlogView> GetBlogViewsToday(IBlogViewRepository repo)
{
    return repo
        .GetAllQueryAble()
        .Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DateAdded) == DateTime.Today)
        .Select(p => p).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: The `.Select(p => p).AsEnumerable();` in there does very little, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like:

```
public interface IHazDateAdded {
   DateTime DateAdded {get;}
}
// extend the types (fortunately we can do this in partial classes)
public partial class Foo : IHazDateAdded {}
public partial class Bar : IHazDateAdded {}

private static IQueryable<T> GetToday<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    where T : IHazDateAdded
{
    return source.Where(
         p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DateAdded) == DateTime.Today);
}
```

which would at least allow some reduction of duplicated code. Personally, though, I would advise using a *range* query instead:

```
private static IQueryable<T> GetToday<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    where T : IHazDateAdded
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Today, end = start.AddDays(1);
    return source.Where(p => p.DateAdded >= start && p.DateAdded < end);
}
```

Then you have:

```
private IEnumerable<BlogPost> GetBlogPostToday(IBlogPostRepository blogPost)
{
    return blogPost.GetAllQueryAble().GetToday();
}

private IEnumerable<BlogView> GetBlogViewsToday(IBlogViewRepository blogViewRepo)
{
    return blogViewRepo.GetAllQueryAble().GetToday();
}
```

We can then further extend/reduce that by having:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
    IQueryable<T> GetAllQueryable();
}
interface IBlogPostRepository : IRepository<BlogPost> { /* ... */ }
interface IBlogViewRepository : IRepository<BlogView> { /* ... */ }
```

allowing:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetToday<T>(IRepository<T> repository)
    where T : IHazDateAdded
{
    return repository.GetAllQueryAble().GetToday();
}
```